# qt drag and drop in qgraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsitem

I have 2 custom qgraphicsitems on a qgraphicsScene, rendered by a qgraphicsview. Now I want to be able to drag and drop one of the 2 items to the other kind. But which events should I reimplement for this? The documentation is a bit confusing on this.

also I want the qgraphicsitem to jump back to its original position if the user drags it to another area than the qgraphicsitem it should be dropped on.

Comment: [These examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-draganddrop.html) could help you out a little bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i know this is not implemented in the QGraphicsScene itself.
You must derive your own class from QGraphicsView or QGraphicsScene and then overload:

```
class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT;
protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    ...
private:
    QGraphicsItem *currentDraggedItem;
};
```

QGraphicsView gives works with view/window coordinates while QGraphicsScene works with Scene coordinates.

Add code like:

```
void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    currentDraggedItem = itemAt(event->pos());

    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
void MyGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    QGraphicsItem *foundItem = itemAt(event->pos());
    if(foundItem && currentDraggedItem && 
       foundItem != currentDraggedItem)
    {
       // Handle DragDrop Here
    }

    QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

This does the job for *one* QGaphicsScene. If you have two of them - the both have to know each other and you must translate coordinates from the one QGraphicsView to the other QGraphicsView. using mapTo...().

Comment: oh but it doesn't have to use the qgraphicsview coordinates, i just want to implement a simple drag one qgraphicsitem on the other and make somehting happen, in my case, I'm making a scrabble game, and I want to drag a character on a tile :d

Comment: So you better derive from QGraphicsScene. Its not hard to do. Also added some more code.

Comment: ok thanks, I'm just a beginner, I'm starting to think this is way over my head :S

Comment: @CédricVandelaer, it's not that hard, just a learning curve and rewarding at the end.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR, there's nothing wrong with inheriting from QGraphicsView or QGraphicsScene, but personally, I think it may be easier to inherit from QGraphicsItem and check for the mouse events from there.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is checking the QGraphicsItems rect and seeing if they intersect.

So, when the mouse down is pressed on an item, store its current position. You can now move it and wait for the mouse release. On the release of the mouse button, check if the bounding rects of the items intersect with QRect::contains(const QRectF). If they do, then you've dropped one onto the other. If not, then animate the graphics item back to the previously stored position.

Just make sure that when you're checking the bounding rects for intersection that you're doing this with both of them in scene space coordinates. Either convert them, or use QGraphicsItem::sceneBoundingRect().

Comment: hmm but all the items are on 1 view, and also how do I send the information from the qgraphicsitem to the other qgraphicsitem where it is dropped on?

Comment: Question now edited, though I'm not sure what you mean by transfer the information from one to the other. Do you mean its position, or something else? Surely it's a matter of getting parameters from one and setting the other, is it not?

Comment: yes it probably is, I'm making a scrabble game, and I have the character tiles (which also contain the score for putting that letter on a tile, and i have the tiles where the character tiles should be dropped on, thanks for the help btw